# Using await and still getting a dbcontext has been disposed error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have read up on Linq that it is lazy-loading so it will likely lead to a `dbcontext` error.  However, I am using `await` which from my understanding waits until the Linq query has finished.  However, I am still getting `dbcontext has been disposed error`.  Here is my code

```
   public async Task DeleteAudit(int mInt)
    {
        var audit = await _AuditRepository.FindBy(a => a.MInt == mInt).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        _AuditRepository.Delete(audit );

         await _AuditRepository.SaveChangesAsync();

    }
```

What I am trying to do is delete a row from _AuditRepository where the mInt matches.

Comment: `I am using await which from my understanding waits until the Linq query has finished.`  No, that's not what it does.  It runs the remainder of the method as a continuation of the task being awaited and then immediately returns control to the caller so it can continue executing code.  The whole point is that it *doesn't* just wait.

Comment: This isn't enough to reproduce the problem; you haven't shown how this method is used, the scope of the repository, when it's disposed, etc.

Comment: `await` doesn't solve lazy-loading issues. In fact, `await` interacts rather poorly with lazy-loading. If you're going to use asynchronous queries, I recommend that you do not use lazy loading at all.

Comment: I'm not sure this has anything to do with await. how is your repository created? is the dbcontext in fact disposed when you call findby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you will need somethink like this, to make this transaction atomic.

```
    public async Task DeleteAudit(int mInt)
    {
        var ctx = new _AuditRepository(connectionString);
        var audit = await ctx.FindBy(a => a.MInt == mInt).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        _AuditRepository.Delete(audit);

        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        ctx.Dispose()

    }
```